# Error running NetAnim from QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt5, qtsvg

I  have QtCreator based on Qt version 5.2.1
I'm building NetAnim app.

It builds with no errors but when I try to run the application I have errors.

In case of **RELEASE** build I get the following error
"Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50101) with this library (version 0x50201)"

I checked and found that I have QtCreator based on QT version 5.2.1 but the Qt5Svg.dll file in my system is based on Qt 5.1.1 (I tried searching online for a version based on 5.2.1 but I couldn't find it)

In case of **DEBUG** build, it get the following warning 
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 768x768+0+0 on QWidgetWindow/'QTabWidgetClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  768x750+0+0 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).

And once I load an XML file everything crashes.

Any suggestions for a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the 5.2.1 version of QtSvg by the proper library installation, however it is possible to get the source of the module yourself and build it for your OS version with your preferred toolchain from [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/submodules/qtsvg-opensource-src-5.2.1.zip).

Please make sure you do not have stray installations around that QtCreator would pick up.